# Layout bug in user profile for answers with a negative score (Chrome)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

In Google Chrome (stable) I noticed the following bug in [a user profile](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9918/proales) with a negative answer score:

[image: screenshot]

The bug does not occur in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem has gone away in the 3 years since this was posted, and that user has since been deleted.